# gpg list keys error trustdb is not writable

Tags: gnupg

When I try to list my gpg keys I'm getting an error:

```
gpg --list-keys
gpg: NOTE: trustdb not writable
gpg: checking the trustdb
gpg: trustdb rec 56: write failed (n=-1): Bad file descriptor
gpg: trustdb: sync failed: Bad file descriptor
```

I tried doing a recursive chown on my user directory. But that didn't seem to solve the problem.

The volume is not read only:

```
  [web1:~] bluethundr% touch test
[web1:~] bluethundr% echo hi > test
[web1:~] bluethundr% cat test
hi
```

So I'm wondering why the trustdb is not writable.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to have been reported in [bug 771976](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=771976)

> I found this when running the command `apt-key list` on a machine where
>   the root filesystem is normally mounted read-only.
>   This results in running `gpg` with "`--trustdb-name`", "`/etc/apt//trustdb.gpg`", "`--list-keys`".
>   `gpg` in turn attempts to create "`/etc/apt//trustdb.gpg.lock`" in order to lock the `trustdb`, which fails.
>
> Seeing how `--list-keys` is an operation which shouldn't require writing
>   to anything, having it fail in this situation is bad.

Even though the volume is not read-only, check (with an strace) where `gpg --list-key` is attempting to create its `trustdb.gpg.lock` file.

```
 strace gpg --list-key | grep trustdb.gpg.lock
```

---

The [OP bluethundr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1017466/bluethundr) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916857/gpg-list-keys-error-trustdb-is-not-writable/47373115#comment87076014_47373115):

> I changed to the `.gnupg` directory and did a list.
>   I saw that the files in there were owned by `root`! So I did a `sudo chown -R myuser:myuser *`.
>   Then I ran `gpg --list-keys` again and it worked!
>   **The problem was that the files in `.gnupg` were owned by `root` for some reason**.

Comment: I changed to the .gnupg directory and did a list. I saw that the files in there were owned by root! So I did a sudo chown -R myuser:myuser *. 

Then I ran gpg --list-keys again and it worked! The problem was that the files in .gnupg were owned by root for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I granted the permissions on the trustdb.gpg file present in the installation directory in C Drive, to the user I had logged on with. It worked thereafter.